# Testing specific apps in Django

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

As far as I know, it is possible to run tests for either all installed apps or a single app. Testing all apps seem to be as an overkill as it usually contains also Django's native modules (`django.contrib.auth` etc). Is it possible to create a test suite containing only apps I specify (which would cointain all tests from all apps in my project folder in my case)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could write a custom test runner that only tests your apps. in the past i've used something like

`tests/runner.py`:

```
from django.test.simple import DjangoTestSuiteRunner
from django.conf import settings

class AppsTestSuiteRunner(DjangoTestSuiteRunner):
    """ Override the default django 'test' command, include only
        apps that are part of this project
        (unless the apps are specified explicitly)
    """


    def run_tests(self, test_labels, extra_tests=None, **kwargs):
        if not test_labels:
            PROJECT_PREFIX = 'my_project.'
            test_labels = [app.replace(PROJECT_PREFIX, '')
                for app in settings.INSTALLED_APPS
                if app.startswith(PROJECT_PREFIX)]
        return super(AppsTestSuiteRunner, self).run_tests(
              test_labels, extra_tests, **kwargs)
```

you then set this as your default test runner in `settings.py`

```
TEST_RUNNER = 'my_project.tests.runner.AppsTestSuiteRunner'
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you'd have to run the tests without the Django test runner.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/#running-tests-outside-the-test-runner

Answer (score 1):

use [nose](http://readthedocs.org/docs/nose/en/latest/) and [django nose](https://github.com/jbalogh/django-nose)

After configuration, just run

> ./manage.py test

and it will just your apps tests.